# How are ashtaka-shrAddha and preta-shraddha performed?

Tags: rituals, pitru

What are these shraddhas and how are they done?

Which texts give procedure for these rituals?

Comment: For both of ur recent questions Scripture is a valid tag. Because in both "As per scriptures" part is understood.

Answer (score 2):

I can only tell you of Preta Shraddha which is quoted in Chapter 10 of Mahanirvana Tantra. However I only have a picture of the source because I could not copy it. It is closely related to the ending of Ekoddhistha Shraddha.

[image]